# Avoid the the cell being reset to null on focus with forceSelection:true

Tags: extjs

I'm trying a `combobox` with a `forceSelection:true`  in the grid but the cell gets reset to null on focus. Can anyone help me, to write a function to retain the previous value on focus. Also if I want to update the cell value to null i.e I just want to clear the cell value? What can be done?

Hoping for a Quick response.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        run();
    }
});

function run() {
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['busname', 'time', 'typebus',],
        data: [{
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '15:30:00',
            typebus: 'AC Volvo',

        }, {
            busname: 'aaa',
            time: '13:30:00',
            typebus: 'Seater',

        },{
            busname: 'AAAA',
            time: '18:30:00',
            typebus: 'Sleeper',

        },{
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '19:30:00',
            typebus: 'AC Volvo',

        },]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        xtype :'gridpanel',
        itemId:'busTimegrid',
        title: 'BUS DEATILS',
        mapperId:'getBusTime',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            header: 'Bus Name',
            dataIndex: 'busname',
            editor: 'textfield'
        }, {
            text: 'Bus Time',
                dataIndex: 'time',
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            renderer: function (value) {
                if (value instanceof Date)
                    return Ext.util.Format.date(value, 'H:i:s');
                else
                return value;
            },
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'timefield',
                format: 'H:i:s',
                allowBlank: true,
                maskRe: /[0-9,:]/,
            }
        }, {
            header: 'Bus TYpe',
            dataIndex: 'typebus',
            editable:true,
            renderer: function (value) {
                if (Ext.isNumber(value)) {
                    var store = this.getEditor().getStore();
                    return store.findRecord('id', value).get('name');
                }
                return value;
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                editable:true,
                forceSelection:true,
                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    fields: ['id', 'name'],
                    data: [{
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'AC Volvo'
                    }, {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Seater'
                    }, {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'Sleeper'
                    }]
                })

            }
        }],
        selModel: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'cellediting',
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            plugins: ['emptiableCombo'],
                listConfig: {
                    cls: 'x-combo-boundlist-small'

                },
        },
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    }
});
}
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r3p)

Comment: Your sample fiddle is not working can you please update it again?

Comment: @Tejas1991 please check it's working now. Please remove the downVote

Comment: Check this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r8q This problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the value in the store record and the combobox valueField do not match. When you click on a cell to edit, it gets the value from the record in context and tries to set it into the cell editor. You can either change the valueField to 'name' or even better use a column renderer like this:

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        run();
    }
});

function run() {
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'busTypeStore',
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        data: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'AC Volvo'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Seater'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Sleeper'
        }]
    });
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['busname', 'time', 'typebus',],
        data: [{
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '15:30:00',
            typebus: 1,

        }, {
            busname: 'aaa',
            time: '13:30:00',
            typebus: 2,

        },{
            busname: 'AAAA',
            time: '18:30:00',
            typebus: 3,

        },{
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '19:30:00',
            typebus: 1,

        },]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        xtype :'gridpanel',
        itemId:'busTimegrid',
        pageSize:3,
        title: 'BUS DEATILS',
        mapperId:'getBusTime',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            header: 'Bus Name',
            dataIndex: 'busname',
            editor: 'textfield'
        }, {
            text: 'Bus Time',
                dataIndex: 'time',
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            renderer: function (value) {
                if (value instanceof Date)
                    return Ext.util.Format.date(value, 'H:i:s');
                else
                return value;
            },
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'timefield',
                format: 'H:i:s',
                allowBlank: true,
                maskRe: /[0-9,:]/,
            }
        }, {
            header: 'Bus TYpe',
            dataIndex: 'typebus',
            editable:true,
            renderer: function (value) {
                var rec = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('busTypeStore').findRecord('id', value);
                return rec.get('name');
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                editable:true,
                forceSelection:true,
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('busTypeStore')

            }
        }],
        selModel: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'cellediting',
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            plugins: ['emptiableCombo'],
                listConfig: {
                    cls: 'x-combo-boundlist-small'

                },
        },
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
}
```

Comment: But it dioesn't allow me to enter a null value. I.e.. if i just want to clear the cell??/ how should I??/

Comment: Did you even try adding a debugger in your column renderer? Doesn't look like it! This is not a problem with the combo and not related to the answer above. When you clear the value from combo, the column renderer gets the record value as null. But since we fetched a record with name as '', the record is not found and undefined. In the code above just try the below condition, works aboslutely fine! --> 
return rec ? rec.get('name') : '';